# 2 questions regarding basic functions

Tags: functions

Consider two functions, $f:A \to A$ and $g:A \to A$.

- a) Prove that if $f:A\to A$ isn't onto, then $f \circ g$ isn't
  onto.
- b) Prove that if $g$ isn't onto and $f$ is one-to-one, then $f
     \circ g$ isn't onto.

For both questions I have difficulty with the first few steps. For example, in question a, I assume $f \circ g$ to be onto. I try to get to a contradiction, but when looking I can't find one.

My attempt goes like this (please consider that I don't study mathematics in english, so if some of my terms are off, feel free to correct me. also - I'm fairly new to math, so keep that in mind).

a) $f$ is not onto. If so, exists $a \in A$ such that for every $b \in A$, $f(b)\not=a$. Assume $f \circ g$ to be onto. If so, for every $y \in A$ exists $x \in A$ such that $f\circ g(x)=y$

I have no clue what to do from here. Same for b). Especially in b), I have no idea where to use the one-to-one property.

Comment: You should use \to in LaTeX for a rightward arrow.

Comment: To avoid being downvoted it's a good idea to show what thoughts you have about the problem, or what effort you've made to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea in the first part of a), you just need to follow it through.  So, $(f \circ g)(a)$ can also be written $f(g(a))$ and in this case, $f$ can only map elements of $A$ that have already been mapped by $g$.  Intuitively we see that if $f$ wasn't **onto** when it was allowed to look at all of $A$, then it won't be **onto** when it's restricted to $g(A) (:= \{b\in A: b = g(a)\})$

Putting that a little more mathematically, and using what you've already done: we know that because $f$ is not **onto** there is some $a\in A$ such that $f(b)\not= a \ \forall b \in A$.  Since $g(A) \subseteq A$ (because $g:A \rightarrow A$) we also know that $f(b) \not= a \ \forall b \in g(A)$.  Hence $f\circ g$ is not **onto**.

You might need to think about the above for a little bit to see how it works.  Try drawing a diagram of what $f$ and $g$ do to the set $A$ and that should help you see exactly how all this works.

For part b), we now know that $g$ is not **onto** and that f is **one-to-one**.  So this time we know that $\exists a\in A$ such that $g(b) \not= a \ \forall b\in A$ -- same as we have for $f$ in part a).  So, specifically (we hinted this at this above) $g(A) \subset A$.  If we knew that $A$ was finite we'd have finished: since $f$ is **one-to-one** it can only map $\#g(A)$ elements to elements in $A$ and that will miss some elements out (draw a picture again!).  For infinite $A$ we have to work a little harder.

Suppose $f \circ g$ *is* **onto**.  Then for each $a \in A$ we have some $b\in g(A)$ such that $f(b) = a$ (because $f: g(A) \rightarrow A$)  Since this is a **one-to-one** relationship we can invert it: $b = f^{-1}(a)$.  Since $f$ is **onto** $f^{-1}(A)=A$.  But that means that $g(A) = A$ and we know, because $g$ is not **onto**, that $g(A) \not= A$.  This is a contradiction, so our assumption that $f \circ g$ was **onto** must have been wrong.  Which proves part b.